# cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to build a tag system within my API.
I have a model which has "Tags" attached to it like this:

```
public class Screenshot: UserExtension
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(2083)] public string Url { get; set; }
    public int StartTime { get; set; }
    public int EndTime { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }

    public IList<ScreenshotTag> Tags { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ScreenshotVideo> Videos { get; set; }
}
```

The **ScreenshotTag** just looks like this:

```
public class ScreenshotTag
{
    public int ScreenshotId { get; set; }
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public Screenshot Screenshot { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

And a **Tag** is really simple (for now)

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key] public string Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ScreenshotTag> Tags { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<VideoTag> Videos { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, I want to modify the **Screenshot** tags in one go. So I created this endpoint:

```
public async Task<bool> Handle(ScreenshotTagUpdate query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var request = query.Model;
    var screenshot = await _mediator.Send(new ScreenshotGet(request.Id), cancellationToken);
    var model = screenshot.Create();

    foreach (var tag in model.Tags)
        if (!request.Tags.Any(m => m.Equals(tag.TagId)))
            _databaseContext.Remove(tag);

    foreach (var tag in request.Tags)
    {
        if (model.Tags.Any(m => m.TagId.Equals(tag))) continue;

        await _tagValidator.ValidateAsync(new Tag {Id = tag}, cancellationToken);
        _databaseContext.Add(new ScreenshotTag { ScreenshotId = request.Id, TagId = tag });
    }

    await _databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    return true;
}
```

As you can see I only call **SaveChangesAsync** once. This is after I have removed or added **ScreenshotTags**. When I run this code I get this error:

> The instance of entity type 'ScreenshotTag' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{ScreenshotId: 1, TagId: th-1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

This error happens on the first `_databaseContext.Remove(tag)`. Does anyone know how I can stop this from happening?

Comment: Try removing and adding to the tracking entity instead of doing it to  _databaseContext, and call just save changes to _databaseContext, in this case, I think that your tracking entity is screenshot or model because I'm see that you are performing a get, I just guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my method to this:

```
public async Task<bool> Handle(ScreenshotTagUpdate query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var request = query.Model;
    var screenshot = await _mediator.Send(new ScreenshotGet(request.Id), cancellationToken);
    var model = screenshot.Create();

    foreach (var tag in model.Tags)
        if (!request.Tags.Any(m => m.Equals(tag.TagId)))
        {
            var t = _databaseContext.ScreenshotTags.Single(m =>
                m.TagId == tag.TagId & m.ScreenshotId == tag.ScreenshotId);
            _databaseContext.Remove(t);
        }

    foreach (var tag in request.Tags)
    {
        if (model.Tags.Any(m => m.TagId.Equals(tag))) continue;

        await _tagValidator.ValidateAsync(new Tag {Id = tag}, cancellationToken);
        _databaseContext.Add(new ScreenshotTag { ScreenshotId = request.Id, TagId = tag });
    }

    await _databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    return true;
}
```

I don't like the solution, so if anyone has a better one, please feel free to add it!

PS: the only like I changed was:

```
_databaseContext.Remove(tag);
```

to:

```
var t = _databaseContext.ScreenshotTags.Single(m =>
    m.TagId == tag.TagId & m.ScreenshotId == tag.ScreenshotId);
_databaseContext.Remove(t);
```